# SQL Maximum number of orders

Tags: sql

I have this task:

Write a query to find out in which year the maximum number of orders was made by the company.
How do i write it?

This is everything I could do, but it is not what I need at all...

```
SELECT company_name, order_date
 FROM customers
 INNER JOIN orders
 ON customers.order_id = orders.order_id
 WHERE order_date = (SELECT MAX(order_date) FROM orders)
 GROUP BY customer_id, order_date;
```

Comment: Can you provide more info, like, table structure and some sample data to give a better understanding and also the out of the above query and how it is different from what you are expecting.

Comment: Also, it is a good practice to tag in the database as well to factor in the syntax change across different db.

Comment: (1) Tag the database you are using.  (2) What happens if there are ties?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below options - choose top/limit based on your DBMS

If SQL Server

```
SELECT top 1 company_name, year(order_date),count(orders.order_id) as total_order
FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders
ON customers.order_id = orders.order_id
GROUP BY company_name, year(order_date)
order by total_order desc
```

OR

If MySQL:

```
SELECT company_name, year(order_date),count(orders.order_id) as total_order
FROM customers
INNER JOIN orders
ON customers.order_id = orders.order_id
GROUP BY company_name, year(order_date)
order by total_order desc limit 1
```

Comment: I think grouping by `customerId` is unnecessary :) OP wants total number of orders all together, not splitted into particular customers.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, hey thanks! for pointing it out :)  it would be company_name

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to aggregate by year and pull the top row.  In standard SQL, that would be:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM o.order_date) as yyyy, COUNT(*) as num_orders
FROM orders o
GROUP BY EXTRACT(year FROM o.order_date)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Note that the exact syntax might vary by database.  For instance, many databases support `YEAR()` in addition to or instead of `EXTRACT()`.  Not all databases support `FETCH FIRST`.  Some use `TOP` or `LIMIT`.  But the above is standard SQL which is the tag on this question.

Also, the `customers` table is not needed for the query.  No `JOIN` is needed.